# Python List index out of range when traversing list/json Object

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a REST API call and taking in the result as a json object, to traverse this i am using this

```
responsereport = urllib2.urlopen(requestreport)

jsondatareport = responsereport.read()
data = json.loads(jsondatareport)

i = 0
while i < data['totalRows']:
    if (data['rows'][i]['visits'] >= 10) :
        print data['rows'][i]['customVariable1']
    i = i+1
```

I keep getting a "IndexError: list index out of range"

What am i doing wrong?

This is the object im traversing....

{u'rows': [{u'conversions': 1, u'roi': 1661.9, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 33.333, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 12.333, u'customVariable1': u'5425', u'profit': 34.9, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 33.333, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 100.0, u'epc': 37.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 1, u'roi': 2542.9, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 18.5, u'customVariable1': u'157971', u'profit': 35.6, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 50.0, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 100.0, u'epc': 37.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 1, u'roi': -11.905, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 36.667, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 0.61667, u'customVariable1': u'135954', u'profit': -5.0, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 60, u'cv': 1.6667, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 42.0, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 4.5455, u'epc': 1.6818, u'clicks': 22, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 1, u'roi': 340.48, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 58.333, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 3.0833, u'customVariable1': u'7902', u'profit': 28.6, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 12, u'cv': 8.3333, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 8.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 14.286, u'epc': 5.2857, u'clicks': 7, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 1, u'roi': 151.7, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 47.619, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 1.7619, u'customVariable1': u'133562', u'profit': 22.3, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 21, u'cv': 4.7619, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 14.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 10.0, u'epc': 3.7, u'clicks': 10, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 1, u'roi': 780.95, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 37.0, u'epv': 6.1667, u'customVariable1': u'8237', u'profit': 32.8, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 16.667, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 33.333, u'epc': 12.333, u'clicks': 3, u'cpv': 0.7},  {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'128287', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 40.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'129859', u'profit': -7.0, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 10, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 7.0, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 4, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'129920', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'130027', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'130290', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'130621', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 40.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13064', u'profit': -3.5, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 5, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 3.5, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 33.333, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'130738', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'131196', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'131211', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'131260', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13135', u'profit': -2.8, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 4, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.8, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'131458', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'131742', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 40.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13274', u'profit': -3.5, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 5, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 3.5, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'132977', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133456', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133493', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133517', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133680', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133806', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 66.667, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'133922', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'134615', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'134829', u'profit': -4.2, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'135415', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 25.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'136033', u'profit': -2.8, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 4, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.8, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13610', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'136522', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'136691', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'136747', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'137243', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'137568', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'137586', u'profit': -4.2, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13764', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'13766', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'139428', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'139863', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'140407', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'140595', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'140596', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 14.286, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'14076', u'profit': -4.9, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 7, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.9, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 16.667, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'141783', u'profit': -4.2, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'141871', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'142398', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'142423', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'142467', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'142874', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'143707', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'144063', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'144064', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'145034', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'145479', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'146752', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'147127', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'147845', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'148506', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'148668', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'148771', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'149518', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'149757', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'150240', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 16.667, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'151851', u'profit': -4.2, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'152803', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 33.333, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'153693', u'profit': -4.2, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 6, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.2, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'153696', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'155712', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'155864', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'157067', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 40.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'158033', u'profit': -3.5, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 5, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 3.5, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'158958', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'159075', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'159743', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'159748', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 50.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'159794', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 0.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'159914', u'profit': -0.7, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 1, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 0.7, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 0, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 66.667, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'160165', u'profit': -2.1, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 3, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 2.1, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 14.286, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'160169', u'profit': -4.9, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 7, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 4.9, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 1, u'cpv': 0.7}, {u'conversions': 0, u'roi': -100.0, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'hour': 1452981600000, u'ctr': 100.0, u'revenue': 0.0, u'epv': 0.0, u'customVariable1': u'160408', u'profit': -1.4, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 2, u'cv': 0.0, u'ap': 0.0, u'cost': 1.4, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 0.0, u'epc': 0.0, u'clicks': 2, u'cpv': 0.7}], u'truncated': False, u'totalRows': 153, u'totals': {u'conversions': 7, u'roi': -31.354, u'advertiserCost': 0.0, u'errors': 0, u'ctr': 30.798, u'revenue': 259.0, u'epv': 0.48052, u'profit': -118.3, u'ictr': 0.0, u'visits': 539, u'cv': 1.2987, u'ap': 37.0, u'cost': 377.3, u'impressions': 0, u'cr': 4.2169, u'epc': 1.5602, u'clicks': 166, u'cpv': 0.7}, u'limit': 100, u'offset': 0, u'customColumns': {}}

Comment: Just do `for row in data['rows']:` or `for dct in data['rows']` may be more apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
for row in data['rows']:
    if row['visits'] >= 10:
       print row['customVariable1']
```

I ran over your dict, it seems the number of rows in `rows` is 84 which is less than the value of `totalRows`. So that's the reason you're getting this error.

Check the API call as to why this is happening.